# Any way to let a user draw an image in google colab and get the resulting image data?

Tags: html5-canvas, google-colaboratory

I can see that there are ways of uploading files to google colab for processing, but it would be really good if there was a way for a user to draw a simple image to test out visual recognition of some systems, i.e MNIST numbers, giving the users a 28x28 grid to draw a number and see what the model predicts it to be.

So there are plenty of examples of how to do this sort of thing on codepen and some premade js libs for being able to just create simple pixel editors components on a canvas, but has anyone found an approach which lets you get something like this on a colab document, lets the user input the data then fetch the data from the drawn image?

Answer (score 3):

I make a gist for doing just that.

https://gist.github.com/korakot/8409b3feec20f159d8a50b0a811d3bca

The main part is this sending data from JS

```js
var data = new Promise(resolve=>{
  button.onclick = ()=>{
    resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))
  }
})
```

And this receiving data in Python.

```py
def draw(filename='drawing.png', w=400, h=200, line_width=1):
  display(HTML(canvas_html % (w, h, line_width)))
  data = eval_js("data")
  binary = b64decode(data.split(',')[1])
  with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(binary)
  return len(binary)
```